# When to use "désigner", "représenter", "signifier", and "symboliser"?

Tags: choix-de-mot

I'm currently staying in a Japanese onsen ryokan, and wanted to explain to my friend what this pictogram denotes, just in case. I said:

> Ça parle de soi-même, ce pictogramme, non ? J’imagine que tu en as déjà vu pas mal, mais les trois lignes parallèles en zigzag **représentent** de la vapeur s’échappant de l’eau chaude du onsen, et elles est entourées d’un cercle **désignant** le bord rond d’un grand bassin.

When explaining Japanese-related stuff, I often find myself in two minds about which to choose between these four verbs. I picked "représenter" and "désigner", but I wonder how other options would stack up in this specific instance?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Dans le contexte de ta phrase, j'aurais choisi l'usage du verbe **représenter** dans les deux instances.
La **représentation** évoque à l'esprit une idée sans la remplacer. Alors que **symboliser** va plus loin que la représentation en indiquant l'idée en son entièreté. De plus, il est chargé en émotions. *"Un crâne symbolise la mort."*
Le verbe **désigner** signifie une indication déterminée et fixée : *"Ce panneau désigne l'acte de céder le passage."* Il va plus loin dans l'évocation que le verbe représenter, mais différemment du verbe symboliser, il est neutre et factuel. C'est pour cette raison qu'il est aussi utilisé en parlant de nomination à une fonction quelconque. *"X fut désigné ministre de l'intérieur."*
Finalement, le verbe **signifier** donne du sens à une idée, un comportement, un évènement. *"Que signifie ce vacarme?" "Il s'agit d'une mutinerie!"* ou encore *"Sa moue signifiait qu'elle n'était pas contente."*

Ainsi, le pictogramme en son entièreté désigne l'Onsen avec les lignes représentant la vapeur qui se dégage, et le cercle représentant le bassin.

Answer (score 0):

*Représentent* and *symbolisent* are the best choices here. I wouldn't use the other ones for not being very idiomatic.

Comment: Indeed for the "soi-même"! What was I thinking? Do you mean to say that you'd use "représenter" for the first and "symboliser" for the second?

Comment: They are almost synonymous. Any combination would work including repeating either of them.

Comment: We could expect some similarity between a representation and what it represents, whereas a symbol can be associated with what it symbolises by mere convention. But I guess these nuances are only relevant when the terms are used in a technical meaning (in philosophical analysis for instance), and they don't really matter for every day speech.

Comment: "signifier" and "designer" are more specifically linguistic, i.e. they generally apply to sentences and words of which they explain the meaning (although not always: "designer quelqu'un" means "to pick someone").

Comment: Why don't you native French speakers help the OP with the French? Ça parle de soi-même?? Elles est entourées?

Comment: @Lambie *Ça parle de soi-même* is tricky. and a mistake native French speakers might do too but that should be *Il parle de lui-même*. The second issue is a mere *faute d'inattention*, no big deal. The OP would certainly have spot it by proofreading the sentence.

Comment: @jlliagre Il parle de lui-même. Mais pas ici. Il  me semble que l'idée serait: Ce pictogramme s'explique tout seul. Je ne  pense pas que:  "parler de soi-même" s'applique aux choses.

Comment: @Lambie C'est une erreur. L'expression idiomatique *parler de soi-même* s'applique couramment à des choses : *Les chiffres parlent d'eux-mêmes*.

Comment: @jlliagre parler de soi-même means to ***talk about oneself***. Les chiffres parlent d'eux-mêmes means "The numbers or figures speak for themselves". Oeuf corse. Ce n'est pas la même chose du tout que: ça parle de soi-même. Ce qui ne veut rien dire. That speaks for itself. Même quand c'est rétrotraduit.

Comment: @Lambie Tu ne sembles pas connaître la locution, regarde ici: https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/parler_de_soi-m%C3%AAme

Comment: @jlliagre Il ne faut pas charrier. "That" speaks for itself (ça parle de soi-même) ne va pas avec le contexte ici. Elle voulait dire que L'image s'explique tout seul, voyons. Et pas que l'image parle de soi-même [speaks for itself]. Et puis, je l'ai traduit correctement vers l'anglais.

Comment: @Lambie Est-ce que tu as vraiment lu ma réponse à ton commentaire ? Pourquoi me bassiner avec *ça parle de soi-même* alors que j'ai écris que je préférais ***IL (le pictogramme) PARLE DE LUI-MÊME***, ce que tu ne sembles toujours pas comprendre et accepter ? *Ça parle de soi-même* est quand même possible en français. Regarde par exemple le titre de [cette photo](https://www.tripadvisor.fr/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g187221-d3833354-i111804535-Restaurant_Plage_Soleil-Cannes_French_Riviera_Cote_d_Azur_Provence_Alpes.html).

Comment: Je souhaite revenir au commentaire de @jlliagre : Almost synonymous does imply a hint of nuance. I wouldn't use the verbe *symboliser* unless the target idea is an abstract concept or to be a bit dramatic. *"De Gaulles symbolise une France qui se veut libre."*, *"Le rose symbolise la féminité."* I'm sorry if I'm being pedantic, but I thought it would've been better to point out.

Comment: As for the *debate* around **parler de soi-même**. It's a common one. En français moderne, il est tendance de n'utiliser *soi-même* qu'avec un article indéfini (Tout un chacun, on, sujet absent) e.g *"Il faut pardonner, quand soi-même on a besoin de pardon."* Alors qu'en littérature classique, il est très courant, voire systématique, de trouver l'usage du pronom soi-même pour la troisième personne du singulier, quelque soit le sujet.*"Possédé d'un ennui qu'il ne saurait dompter, Il craint d'être à soi-même et songe à s'éviter"*. But it does feel a bit heavy on the tongue.

Comment: To jlliagre: I highly doubt it, but do you notice anything odd about "entourées"?

Comment: Yes, that should be *elles **sont** entourées* (*les trois lignes*!)

Comment: LoL! I was so focused on "entourées" that I hadn't even noticed it. It's funny how we are incapable of editing our own writing. He was once again nit-picking for the sake of nit-picking, eh? People don't change overnight, I guess.

Comment: No problem, it happens all the time :-)

Comment: "to speak for itself" is said quite commonly in English and feels natural in that language; in French the literal translation has not been used, feels unnatural for that reason,  has merely been forced into the language by business people and of course it comes straight out of the English language; I will not use it in French. I should add this: for "speak for itself" think "auto-explicatif"; pour "parler de soi-même" think "have a talk about oneself".