# What is wrong with "Je parle bon français"?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, déterminants

I recently learned that to say "I speak good French", that saying

> Je parle bon français.

makes it sound like you *don't* speak good French!

What is incorrect about "Je parle bon français"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrasing « je parle (le) bon français » does sound odd if you want to say "I speak French well/fluently". As long as the adjective "bon" qualifies the noun "français", it sounds as if there are multiple variants of the French language and ...

> I speak **a sophisticated / refined / good type of** French (among them) –  that is, the kind of language with impeccable grammar, a more elevated level of vocabulary etc.

Rather than *tinkering* with the noun "français" by adding some adjective, you usually use an adverb like "bien/couramment" instead to have it qualify the verb "parler":

> Je parle **bien**/**couramment** français.

---

On the other hand, if you do have the meaning of "a sophisticated type of French" in mind, you can grammatically say something like:

> Qu'est-ce que ça te coûte de parler **le *bon*** français de temps en temps ?

... with a definite article "le" preceding the adjective "bon" – preferably in Italic.

You can also say the following with essentially the same meaning:

> Qu'est-ce que ça te coûte de parler **en *bon*** français de temps en temps ?

Note: An (in)definite article cannot be placed immediately following the preposition "en". A similar example: « avoir une bonne santé » vs « être en bonne santé ».

---

Last but not least...

> Je parle **un** bon français. === Je parle bien français.

Adding an indefinite article instead of a definite article works, too, but note the difference in meaning between the two: « parler **le** bon français » vs « parler **un** bon français ».

The definite article serves to impart a general, *global* sense to the noun "français" – in that the notion of « **le** bon français / a sophisticated type of French » is something recognised and shared by everyone in society, not just by you.

...Whereas with an indefinite article, the noun "français" takes on a *personal* nature, the focus now being on what level of French proficiency *you* are currently at: « **un** bon français / a good command of French ».

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, the sentence "Je parle bon français" is grammatically correct?

Comment: @silph Answer updated accordingly. I hope this is what your question is all about! Because I can't shake the feeling that you actually want to know about some other aspect of the phrasing...

Comment: actually, I suspect the confusion is that, "I speak good French" and "I speak poor French" sound perfectly okay to my (native-English) ears, so I didn't realize that these sentences could sound awkward to French ears. For example, an anglophone might say (in English), "Oh, sorry, I speak very poor French. Can we talk in English, instead, please?". Or, on the other hand, an anglophone might say (in English) "Oh, it's okay. I speak good French; would you like to talk in French, instead?"

Comment: @silph From an English speaker's perspective, I get where you're coming from. The only thing is that "*je parle (le) mauvais francais*" in the sense of "*je ne parle pas bien français*" is not a standard turn of phrase in French -- if not impossible.

Comment: The case is interestingly more complicated than this, though, given « en bon français » ! But I agree about « Je parle bon français » not working. I wonder why the one exists and not the other. (For some reason I'm also reminded of ["Laüstic" by Marie de France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La%C3%BCstic), where she says "This is *rossignol* in French, or *nihtegale* **en droit anglais**"...)

Comment: Although I wouldn't question OP's implied premise that "I speak good English/French" (in English) is "grammatically correct," I would question whether it "sounds perfectly okay" across the English-speaking world, for in my small part of "Anglophonia" (central Virginia, USA), what I think would sound ["more"] perfectly OK (when expressing this notion with an adjective rather than an adverb) would be something more like "Oh sorry/it's okay, my French **is** [very] poor/good."  or maybe, ,"I **am** [very] poor/good in French" cc: @LukeSawczak

Comment: @LukeSawczak Hiya. « *Parler en bon français* » is essentially the same in meaning as « *parler le bon français* ». As for why « *parler en bon français* » is grammatical while « *je parle bon français* » is not -- an (in)definite article "*le/un/etc*" cannot be placed right after the preposition "*en*" whereas in « *je parle (le) bon français* », "*le*" is mandatory. Another example: « *avoir une bonne santé* » vs « *être en bonne santé* ». :D

Comment: @PapaPoule Now that you mention it, "*I speak so-so French*" vs "*I speak French so-so*" comes to mind, since "so-so" can be both an adjective and an adverb.

Comment: You might suggest *je parle un bon français* too.

Comment: @jlliagre A nice catch!

Comment: @Alone-ee: would using a partitive article make the sentence grammatical: "Je parle du bon français."?

Comment: @silph For instance, "l'usage **du bon** français" is OK but "Je parle **du bon** français" is not, as there is no reason to use "de" here.

Comment: "Il parle le bon français" is not said; if exceptionnally someone says that it is in reference to two types of French, or possibly more, that the context makes precise; in that case "bon" means "right"; a typical case would be that of someone who can peppers his French with "argot" , or that of someone who distorts skilfully the sounds in some manner (jocular…), or more simply that of someone fluent enough in a regional variant, a regional accent that is recognized as being quite apart from mainstream French.

Comment: @user168676 It seems you haven't fully understood my answer. I mentioned -- "parler le *bon* français" -- "preferably in Italic" -- indicating that this turn of phrase is indeed rather *special*. Also in the 4th comment: "is not a standard". So I'm afraid I fail to see your point here. By the way, I have to disagree with "Il parle le bon français is not said". (The link below) It's even in the title of a book. If its usage were not recognised enough, it wouldn't appear in any publication. I just double-checked this with my French-speaking colleagues.

Comment: https://www.decitre.fr/livres/ecrire-et-parler-le-bon-francais-9782841875108.html

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens At least we agree on that: it is a form of restricted use; my point is "le bon" does not refer to sohisticated variant, does not refer to something in the language that would confer the idea of superiority; it's just a matter of correct French, the normal language that is accepted anywhere and not an unusual sort of French; You understand that a sophisticated French is something rare; that's where I take you up on the book you cite: it is a treatment of good, normal French, according to my characterisation the "right" French;

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens  do you think the subject would be such a particular type of French? In the title, as is the case with many titles, a stance is taken in a somewhat humourous manner: it is the same stance that can be elicited from the examples I gave; I do agree with the comment you refer to: there is no great case for saying "le mauvais français" but ultimately, that also could be said; I should add something: this is question is not restricted to French or even languages; we're dealing with a pattern; ex: Parlez-nous, je vous prie, de la bonne religion, nous ne sommes pas des païens.

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens What would you make of that? Please, pardon my bad typing, there are missing words and other errors. PS "not said" means "almost never"; that is more precise.

Comment: "Parler un bon français" does not mean exactly "bien parler français"; the first insists on the fact that  the person speaks his/her particular brand, where "brand" is not to be understood as signifying a type of French essentially different from standard French but normal French, except that one will recognise in it particularities for which only the person speaking is responsible: a choice of words that is correct but not made by everyone, a choice of forms that are possibly not so common or vice versa and so on; in connection with that context one says: "Her French is good!", etc.

Comment: @user168676 Just be sure that you're not making comments for the sake of griping, finding faults, no matter what. On the same note, just be sure that you're not casting downvotes for the sake of near-trolling, irrelevant to the quality of answers, out of some negative/hostile feelings caused by rejections and such. If you want to be taken seriously, that is. Some members have had their accounts suspended for doing just that. And your comments/downvoting tendency (not just towards me but towards other members as well) show similar traits to this member Lambie.

Comment: @user168676 SE is not for chatting, so this kind of comments is not welcome, even if other members might not say it openly. https://french.stackexchange.com/users/9299/lambie See the endless comments by Lambie below jlliagre's answer, which led to the suspension of his account. https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/28543/when-to-use-d%C3%A9signer-repr%C3%A9senter-signifier-and-symboliser End of discussion. Bye.

Comment: @ Con-gras-tue-les-chiens Vous pouvez bien essayer de noyer le poisson dans l'eau, vous avez bel et bien tort et vous le savez!

Answer (score 2):

I just want to add that "Je parle bon français" is wrong for exactly the same reason that "I speak good English" is wrong for the intended sense.  In both cases, it is your speaking ability that is at stake, so the word you need to modify is the verb, which is modified with an adverb (bien/well).  If you use the adjective (bon/good), then you are qualifying not the verb but the noun, and are referring not to your fluency but to your use of an elite dialect of the language.  That distinction between an adverb modifying a verb and an adjective modifying a noun is both bon français and good English.

Comment: In my part of anglophone Canada, "I speak good English" is a correct sentence, and does in fact refer to my fluency, instead of some elite dialect. Where I live, other correct sentences are "My English is broken/bad/good/fluent", and with these sentences, modifying the noun "English" is okay to do, even though you're trying to convey the level of your speaking ability.